# Create a folder with a custom extension

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

So I've been looking around for a bit on a way to do this, and here is my idea:

I want to create a folder, with a custom extension. Similar to how java has their .jar folders, is there any way to package things like this, and still be able to move things between the folders?

For example, I want to use `.map`, and use it as a folder. So lets say I want to put a `ma.png` and `ma.p` inside of a `test.map` folder, and store all of that inside of a folder named `maps`, so the reference for the `ma.p` file would be `"maps/test.map/ma.p"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no ".jar folders" in Java. Those are files (zip files to be precise)

Comment: You can make a file act like a folder. This is how zip works. But it's not a directory. It's not clear if that is what you are after here.

Comment: @RaymondChen
Yes actually, how would I do that?

Comment: You need to write a shell namespace extension. This is a complex topic that is beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows cannot associate folders with programs the way OS X does. You can name folders with an 'extension', but it doesn't change its behaviour. In OS X, renaming a folder to `something.app` makes the OS treat the folder as a file (application). Windows doesn't do this.

You mentioned `.jar` files: Java archives are `.zip` archives, renamed to `.jar`.

You can do what you said in your last paragraph, but Windows doesn't care about 'extensions' in directory names. This is an OS X-only thing, if you ever see such a thing, I can almost guarantee it's a renamed .zip, rather than a directory with an extension.

Comment: Hmm... so it's not a possibility then?

Comment: You can do what you said in your last paragraph, but Windows doesn't care about 'extensions' in directory names. This is an OS X-only thing, if you ever see such a thing, I can almost guarantee it's a renamed `.zip`, rather than a directory with an extension.

Edit: added this to the answer

Comment: Ok, well either way you helped me out a lot. Lot of time I don't have to waste... Thanks!